# How to add data in new columns based on existing column in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe like this.

```
DF <- data.frame(names = c("john", "bob", "frank", "bill", "sam"),
                 pets  = c("dog", "cat", "mouse", "horse", "bird"))
```

I want to add new data in two different columns based on the data in the second column (pets).

I wrote these two lines of code and it works

```
DF$color[DF$pets == "dog"] <- "red"
DF$ID[DF$pets == "dog"] <- 1
```

How can I group them in just one statement?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
DF[DF$pets == "dog", c("color", "ID")] <- list("red", 1)
```

---

Or do a join

```
library(dplyr)
 left_join(DF, tibble(pets = "dog", color = "red", ID = 1))
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, your first solution is perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to `merge` with a `data.frame`.

You can add one row

```
d1 <- data.frame(pets='dog',
                 color='red', 
                 ID=1)

merge(DF, d1, all=TRUE)
#    pets names color ID
# 1  bird   sam  <NA> NA
# 2   cat   bob  <NA> NA
# 3   dog  john   red  1
# 4 horse  bill  <NA> NA
# 5 mouse frank  <NA> NA
```

and multiple rows (even when there's no owl in DF).

```
d2 <- data.frame(pets=c('dog', 'bird', 'owl'),
                 color=c('red', 'green', 'blue'), 
                 ID=c(1, 2, 3))

merge(DF, d2, all=TRUE)
#    pets names color ID
# 1  bird   sam green  2
# 2   cat   bob  <NA> NA
# 3   dog  john   red  1
# 4 horse  bill  <NA> NA
# 5 mouse frank  <NA> NA
# 6   owl  <NA>  blue  3
```

The data frames get automatically merged by `pets` since it's the shared column name. Look into `?merge` for other options. The result gets alphabetically sorted by `pets`, use `merge(., sort=FALSE)` to switch off that behavior.

---

*Data:*

```
DF <- structure(list(names = c("john", "bob", "frank", "bill", "sam"
), pets = c("dog", "cat", "mouse", "horse", "bird")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```