# How to group selections and repalcements in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a similar post here [How to add data in new columns based on existing column in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75778855/how-to-add-data-in-new-columns-based-on-existing-column-in-a-data-frame) but regarding R.
Now I need the same help with python pandas

I have a dataframe like this.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'names': ["john", "bob", "frank", "bill", "sam"],
     'pets': ["dog", "cat", "mouse", "horse", "bird"]}
DF = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to add new data in two different columns based on the data in the second column (pets).

I wrote these two lines of code and it works

```
DF.loc[DF['pets']=="dog", 'color'] = 'red'
DF.loc[DF['pets']=="dog", 'ID'] = 1
```

How can I group them in just one statement?

Comment: `DF.loc[DF['pets']=="dog", ['color', 'ID']] = ['red', 1]`

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple columns, you can specify the column names as a `list`.

```
>>> DF.loc[DF['pets']=="dog", ['color', 'ID']] = ['red', 1]
>>> DF
   names   pets color   ID
0   john    dog   red  1.0
1    bob    cat   NaN  NaN
2  frank  mouse   NaN  NaN
3   bill  horse   NaN  NaN
4    sam   bird   NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Hi, I get this error "None of [Index(['color', 'ID'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: @ilFonta Are you sure that you are trying exact code from my answer?

Comment: Hi Abdul, yes I did

Comment: You need to add the empty columns before, like DF["color"] = ""
DF["ID"] = ""

Comment: No, You don't need to. The answer is already tested.